# Refresh jTable using binding with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, binding, jtable

I'm working on a project in NetBeans , about a small restaurant.

I have 2 Jtables which i bound to my database and there are 2 form that I use to insert data.First table is to insert employee data and the second one s to insert item details.

I **want the records in the tables to be refreshed with each insert**.So I created 2 refresh methods , pass ( List l) as parameter and copy and paste the binding codes from generated codes and pass l to binding .

But it doesn't work .Why is that ?
**Is there any other way to refresh that table's data ?**

here are my refresh tables

```
private  void refreshItm(List l){
        jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, itemsList, jTable2);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${itemid}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Itemid");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${itemname}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Itemname");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${availablequantity}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Availablequantity");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Short.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${price}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Price");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();
    }

    private void refreshEmp(List l){
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, l, jTable1);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${empid}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Empid");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${empname}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Empname");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${address}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Address");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();
    }
```

Comment: For the question of "other way", you can write your own table model... I know it kind of weird but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update your result list (ie. in your first method "itemsList"). Look for "initComponents" method. Inside this method there should be a line to get "itemsList" like:

```
    itemsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : itemsQuery.getResultList();
```

copy that line to the first line of your method.

Answer (score 0):

As user1545636 suggested you missed to reload the itemsList.
Now I would like to share you a better code design to refresh a jTable after a JPA insert/update/delete operation happened:

In Netbeans, jump to the design tab, right click on your jtable and click on "customize code..."

From the Component drop down list select itemsList and sele "custom creation" in the beneath drop down list.

Now change the itemsList inizialization in from

```
itemsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : itemsQuery.getResultList();
```

to

```
itemsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections.observableList(itemsQuery.getResultList());
```

In this way you made observable the itemsList object.
Now in your refreshItm method write only this code:

```
itemsList.clear();
itemsList.addAll( itemsQuery.getResultList());
```

Call that method after a JPA insert/update/delete and the jTable refreshes automatically like a charm!

I hope you enjoy this solution